# Unable to import maven dependency in New Android Gradle project

Tags: android, maven, github, build.gradle

I am trying to implement a dependency from a Github repo into my new Android Project. But while syncing my app, I am getting this exception

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Here is my project-level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "PixelCraft"
include ':app'
```

And my app-level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.gliesestudio.pixelcraft'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gliesestudio.pixelcraft"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0' //Not getting imported

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Repo: https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library appears to be abandoned.

It was [last published about three years ago, to JCenter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.smarteist/autoimageslider/1.4.0). You can try adding `jcenter()` to the `repositories` closure in the  `dependencyResolutionManagement` closure in your `settings.gradle` file. However, most of the community has abandoned JCenter, as JCenter has largely discontinued its service. See:

- [JCenter service update](https://developer.android.com/build/jcenter-migration)
- [JCenter Shutdown Impact on Gradle Builds](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown)

Personally, I would use `ViewPager2`, or perhaps `HorizontalPager()` from Jetpack Compose, rather than this library. But, if you want to use the library, you may be better served forking the repository and maintaining your own copy of the library.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, thanks for the answer. Actually, I am looking for something that can make auto-horizontal scrolling. If you have any resources related to this, please share them with me. It will be very much appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: @MazidulIslam: "Actually, I am looking for something that can make auto-horizontal scrolling" -- again, I would use `ViewPager2`, or perhaps `HorizontalPager()` from Jetpack Compose.